# Clean up data with PHP by moving position of specific words

Tags: php, cpu-word

I have some data I´d like to clean-up. This should be a common problem but I have not found a solution. The data looks like this and should be converted into:

- Easiest, The -> The Easiest
- Night, The - Is black -> The Night - Is black
- Trip,A - Go west -> A Trip - Go west
- Muse, La: 3 chansons -> La Muse: 3 chansons
- Passion, La (OMG) -> La Passion (OMG)
- Johnny - One to go for, The -> Johnny - The One to go for
- Peace, The "Great one" -> The Peace "Great one"

A special situation is a double occurrence:

- Internet Generation, The - Dream, A -> The Internet Generation - A Dream

Leave as is as there is no "stop" character and the word "the" is not at the end:

- Chuck, the fighter -> Chuck, the fighter

So there are multiple words that need to be moved (the, a, la) to the beginning and several "stop" characters [:,-,(,",end of string]. There can be a whitespace before the comma or not.

I tried to solve the problem with preg_replace but could not come up with a working solution. I am sure it is possible for someone more experienced. I´d very much appreciate your help on this!

Final solution I am using based on [elclanrs´ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18783049/598740):

```
$tests = array(
    "Easiest, The",
    "Heaviest,The",
    "Night, The - Is black",
    "Trip,A - Go west",
    "Muse, La: 3 chansons",
    "Passion, La (OMG)",
    "Johnny - One to go for, The",
    "Peace, The \"Great one\"",
    "Chuck, the fighter",
    "Mason, the hero ",
    "Internet Generation, The - Dream, A",
);

$patt = '/([^,:"(-]+)\s*?,\s*?([^,:"(-]+)/';

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    if (preg_match('/(([:"(-]+)\s*?)|,\s*?\w+\s*?$/', $test)) {
        echo trim(preg_replace('/\s+:/', ':', preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', preg_replace($patt, '$2 $1 ', $test)))) . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "Not modified: " . $test . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

which will give:

```
The Easiest
The Heaviest
The Night - Is black
A Trip - Go west
La Muse: 3 chansons
La Passion (OMG)
Johnny - The One to go for
The Peace "Great one"
Not modified: Chuck, the fighter
Not modified: Mason, the hero 
The Internet Generation - A Dream
```

So I am just skipping the strings which do not need to be modified and removing all unnecessary spaces.

Comment: You said you tried a regex in your question. What was it? How far did you get with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
$tests = array(
    "Easiest, The",
    "Night, The - Is black",
    "Trip,A - Go west",
    "Muse, La: 3 chansonss",
    "Passion, La (OMG)",
    "Johnny - One to go for, The",
    "Peace, The \"Great one\""
);

$patt = '/([^,:"(-]+)\s*?,\s*?([^,:"(-]+)/';

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo preg_replace($patt, '$2 $1 ', $test) .'<br>';
}
```

This will print out:

```
The Easiest 
The Night - Is black
A Trip - Go west
La Muse : 3 chansonss
La Passion (OMG)
Johnny - The One to go for 
The Peace "Great one"
```

You'd have to update the tokens if you have more rules `[^,:"(-]`. It's not perfect as you can see there's a space before the `:`, but I'll leave that and the special cases up to you...

Comment: Fantastic! The space in front of the : is totally acceptable. Thank you!